# Blank screen/project

Tags: qgis

I've been working on a project for a few months. I closed it and re-opened it and since then any of my projects have problems loading, meaning I just get a blank screen (see attached). If I click on any of my layers I get the loading icon, eventually I have to force quit. I'm on MacBook Pro 15 + El Capitan + QGis Essen.[image]
I opened the same project on windows and it's all fine.

Comment: Where is your data being stored? You need to have access to both the data and the project file.

Answer (score 1):

The map was zoomed in on [Null Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island). 
Always check the coordinates shown at the bottom status bar when your data "disappears", it may have panned somewhere else, either by accident, or due to OTF issues.

To correct this, make sure the CRS is set to required one, R-click any working layer and press zoom to layer.